# How to replace a module from branch in the forked project in Go?

Tags: go, github

I have original GH project `github.com/LabA/pkgname/v2` and the forked one `github.com/DisplayName/pkgname/v2`.

I have commit `bc16a32c24` in `github.com/DisplayNameForkedLabA/pkgname/v2`.

This commit has such `go.mod` that contains line:

```
module github.com/LabA/pkgname/v2

...
```

The third project `github.com/LabB/pkgname/v2` uses `github.com/LabA/pkgname/v2`. I want to replace requirement

```
replace (
    github.com/LabA/pkgname/v2 v2.15.1-0.20230704092742-285516a94ebe => github.com/DisplayNameForkedLabA/pkgname/v2 v2.15.1-0.20230710090848-bc16a32c24c3
)
```

I've got `v2.15.1-0.20230710090848-bc16a32c24c3` by

```
go list -json -m github.com/DisplayNameForkedLabA/pkgname/v2@bc16a32c24
```

When I do

```
go get -d github.com/DisplayNameForkedLabA/pkgname/v2@bc16a32c24
```

it says

```
go: github.com/DisplayNameForkedLabA/pkgname/v2@v2.15.1-0.20230710090848-bc16a32c24c3: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: github.com/LabB/pkgname/v2
                but was required as: github.com/DisplayNameForkedLabA/pkgname/v2
```

My assumption is that my fork should have another module name within `go.mod` and refer to my fork.
How do I fix that error and replace the module from the branch in forked project?

Comment: why do you need to run `go get -d github.com/DisplayNameForkedLabA/pkgname`? You are manually replacing a module with that location, there's nothing to `go get`.

Comment: oh. You're right. By the way, I got the errors due to other problem: I should have run `go mod tidy` after that and this worked out! Yes! Thank you anyway